# Firebase data persistence, updating troubles - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

In my firebase database I use persistence to cache the data, but this give me a problem, because some of my data needs to be loaded from the database when the app loads and not from tha cached data. I have a tableview where the data from the database is shown, it needs to update with the database and not look for the saved data in the tableview. Right now I am using

```
 self.ref?.child(u.uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
   print(offersnapshot)
})
```

to get the data from the data from the server. But right now the app needs to restart, before the data are updated.

Comment: The code you share sets up a listener and should (also) be called with the live version from the server. If you have a cached value for that reference and a network connection, the completion handler may fire twice: once for the cached version and once (if it is different) for the version from the server.

Answer (score 2):

From the info you provided i think the problem is you did not enable the syncing of firebase cache data with the firebse server database.
try this:

```
let scoresRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "rootNode")
scoresRef.keepSynced(true)
```

Comment: Should I use the reference inside the snapshot or in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: inside viewDidLoad you can put this code and do not forget to reload the table view in the firebase value observer.